Backup Mariadb from replica
I have cloud server with a MariaDB database that I want to backup.
To avoid use the bandwith to transfer locally generated backup files from the cloud service to my backup server, one of the approaches I'm thinking of is to create a MariaDB replica in my backup server and there performing the backups (logical/physical).
Is this a good/recommended approach?

This is a good idea.
As you pointed out, it would save bandwidth, and it would also actually be faster, because backing up a local replica is generally faster than a remote server.
It would also improve consistency and provide an additional layer of redundancy. This is because the replica would ensure your backup server has an up-to-date copy of data, and ensures that your data is available if the cloud server goes down.
That being said, like anything, there are always things to watch out for. Things will be smooth sailing as long as you:

Configure the replica correctly: Ensure that the replica is set up as a read-only instance to avoid accidental writes to the backup server.
Regularly test your backups: Verify that your backups are complete and restorable from the replica.
Monitor the replica: Keep an eye on the replica's performance, lag, and data consistency to ensure it's working as expected.

As long as you remember to do these simple practices, you’ll have a reliable and efficient backup strategy in place!
